# How to import a Typescript or Javascript file from an external link?

Tags: javascript, node.js, import

I want to use some of the Deno standard libraries in Node.js to create an HTTP server.

I know that I can just download it but I want to stay updated with the latest library so I want to import them like this:

```
import { serve } from "https://deno.land/std/http/server.ts";

// Defining port to be used
const PORT = 8080
// Setting server to listen at port
const server = serve({ port: PORT });
console.log(`This Hello World server is up and running on http://localhost:${PORT}/`);

// Sending Hello World to any client that connects
for await (const req of server) {
    req.respond({ body: "Hello World!\n" });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's theoretically possible to use a limited subset of the Deno `std` library in Node (modules which use nothing from the web APIs, nothing from the Deno API, and include no import statements with specifiers ending in `.ts`).

However, the module from your example at `https://deno.land/std/http/server.ts` does not meet this criteria and will create both compile-time errors in `tsc` (TypeScript) and runtime errors in Node.js.

Comment: wait how to use a limited subset of the Deno std library in Node btw

Comment: @KhánhBảo by downloading the modules locally. (And you can use the URL address specifier by using a combination of [path mapping](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/module-resolution.html#path-mapping) and [subpath imports](https://nodejs.org/api/packages.html#subpath-imports).)

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind I just want to use ES6+ syntax to create a server so I use this:

```js
import https from "https";
import http from "http";

export default class Server {
    readonly server: http.Server | https.Server;

    constructor(options?: http.ServerOptions | https.ServerOptions, httpsMode?: boolean) {
        this.server = (httpsMode ? https : http).createServer(options);
    }

    listen(port?: number, hostname?: string, backlog?: number) {
        let s = this.server;
        s.listen(port, hostname, backlog);
        return {
            [Symbol.asyncIterator]() {
                return {
                    async next() {
                        return {
                            done: false,
                            value: await new Promise<{request: http.IncomingMessage, response: http.ServerResponse}>(result => {
                                s.on('request', (request, response) => 
                                    result({request, response})
                                );
                            })
                        };
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    close() {
        this.server.close();
    }
}
```

This module is available on NPM, package [Newer.js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/newer.js) after I publish 0.0.4